# Control the animation of each layer (composition) for one Lottie file

Tags: flutter, dart, animation, flutter-animation, lottie

I am using the Lottie library (version 2.3.2). I also have a Lottie file, which has several compositions with their own animation. How can I control the animation of each composition individually?

As far as I understand, in older version of this library there was a composition parameter in constructor, which allowed loading a specific composition from a Lottie file. This option is currently not available.